# Spring Boot project with Controller ,Service Layer,DAO Layer

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, servlets

> implementing COntroller,Service Layer,DAO layer in Spring Boot
>
> Created Patient pojo class,

```
package com.hospital.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Patient")
public class Patient {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int tokenNumber;

private String patientName;

private  int phoneNumber;

private int patientAge;

public int getTokenNumber() {
    return tokenNumber;
}

public void setTokenNumber(int tokenNumber) {
    this.tokenNumber = tokenNumber;
}

public String getPatientName() {
    return patientName;
}

public void setPatientName(String patientName) {
    this.patientName = patientName;
}

public int getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public int getPatientAge() {
    return patientAge;
}

public void setPatientAge(int patientAge) {
    this.patientAge = patientAge;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Patient [tokenNumber=" + tokenNumber + ", patientName=" + patientName + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber
            + ", patientAge=" + patientAge + ", getTokenNumber()=" + getTokenNumber() + ", getPatientName()="
            + getPatientName() + ", getPhoneNumber()=" + getPhoneNumber() + ", getPatientAge()=" + getPatientAge()
            + ", getClass()=" + getClass() + ", hashCode()=" + hashCode() + ", toString()=" + super.toString()
            + "]";
}

public Patient(int tokenNumber, String patientName, int phoneNumber, int patientAge) {
    this.tokenNumber = tokenNumber;
    this.patientName = patientName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.patientAge = patientAge;
}

public Patient()
{
    
}

public Patient(String patientName, int phoneNumber, int patientAge) {
    this.patientName = patientName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.patientAge = patientAge;
}
```

}

> Created PatientDAO Interface with abstract method.

```
package com.hospital.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.hospital.entity.Patient;

public interface PatientDAO {

    public Patient patientVerifyByTokenumber(int tokenNumber);

    public List<Patient> listOfAllPatients();

}
```

> Implementing all the methods in PatientDAOImpl(Repository)

```
    package com.hospital.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.hospital.entity.Patient;



@Repository
@Transactional
public class PatientDAOImpl implements PatientDAO {

    
    

@Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;



@Override
@Transactional
public Patient patientVerifyByTokenumber(int tokenNumber) {
    Patient patient =this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Patient.class, new Integer(tokenNumber));
    return patient;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<Patient> listOfAllPatients() {
    List<Patient> patientList=this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Patient").list();
    return patientList;
}
```

}

> In service layer creating Interface. (PatientService)

```
package com.hospital.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.hospital.entity.Patient;


public interface PatientService {
    
    public Patient patientVerifyByTokenumber(int tokenNumber);
    public List<Patient> listOfAllPatients();
}
```

> Implementing Patientservice interface in patientServiceimpl(businness logic code)

```
package com.hospital.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.hospital.dao.PatientDAO;
import com.hospital.dao.PatientDAOImpl;
import com.hospital.entity.Patient;


@Service
public class PatientServiceImpl implements PatientService{
    
    @Autowired
    PatientDAO patientDAO;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public Patient patientVerifyByTokenumber(int tokenNumber) {
        
        return patientDAO.patientVerifyByTokenumber(tokenNumber);
    }

    @Override
    
    public List<Patient> listOfAllPatients() {
        return patientDAO.listOfAllPatients();
    }
}
```

> created one controller

```
package com.hospital.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.hospital.entity.Patient;
import com.hospital.service.PatientService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("patient/")
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    private PatientService service;


    @RequestMapping(value="verify",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Patient patientVerifyByTokenumber(@RequestParam int tokenNumber) {

        return service.patientVerifyByTokenumber(tokenNumber);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="fetchall",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Patient> listOfAllPatients() {
        return service.listOfAllPatients();
    }

}
```

> Spring boot main class

```
package com.hospital.HospitalSystem;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.hospital"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class HospitalSystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HospitalSystemApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean fact = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
        fact.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return fact;
    }
}
```

> Application properties code

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital?useSSL=false
    spring.datasource.username = root
    spring.datasource.password = mysql
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

> Finally i got this error from Entire code, couldn't find out where exactly

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-01 14:51:35.778 ERROR 5336 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   restController (field private com.hospital.service.PatientService com.hospital.controller.RestController.service)
      ↓
   patientServiceImpl (field com.hospital.dao.PatientDAO com.hospital.service.PatientServiceImpl.patientDAO)
      ↓
   patientDAOImpl (field org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.hospital.dao.PatientDAOImpl.sessionFactory)
┌─────┐
|  sessionFactory defined in com.hospital.HospitalSystem.HospitalSystemApplication
└─────┘
```

Comment: Looks like HospitalSystemApplication references itself

Comment: ya.. i created  HospitalSystemApplication with main method

Comment: iy you Need more help Show the relevant code

Comment: i uploded entire code,

Answer (score 0):

Usually in spring boot there is no need to configure the HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean, thanks to auto-configuracion.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HospitalSystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HospitalSystemApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The @SpringBootApplication already has @EnableAutoConfiguration. Also, it will scan the packages where HospitalSystemApplication is located.

Comment: PD: Use Spring Data Jpa ;)